# DataTables FixedColumn Plugin, 2 fixed columns issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) jquery plugin to build an HTML scrolling table with fixed headers and fixed columns.

Everything was working fine with 1 fixed column, but there seems to be a bug if I set more than one fixed column. The first fixed column works normally, but for the others, only the header stay fixed.

This is the javascript I'm using to initialize the DataTable :

```
_$grid.dataTable({
    colReorder: {
        fixedColumnsLeft: 1
    },
    dom: 'Rlfrtip',
    info: false,
    ordering:false,
    paging: false,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scrollY: scrollYSize(), // A function that compute the height of the table wrapper
    scrollX: '100%',
    searching: false,
    fixedColumns: {
        leftColumns: 1 // If leftColumns is set to 2 (or more) the bug appears
    }
});
```

I've tried to initialize the FixedColumns extension this way, same effect :

```
_dataTable = _$grid.dataTable({
    colReorder: {
        fixedColumnsLeft: 2
    },
    dom: 'Rlfrtip',
    info: false,
    ordering:false,
    paging: false,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scrollY: scrollYSize(), // A function that compute the height of the table wrapper
    scrollX: '100%',
    searching: false
});
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(_dataTable, {
    leftColumns: 2 // If leftColumns is set to 2 (or more) the bug appears
})
```

Did you ever facing this problem ?

**EDIT : (screenshot)**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a fiddle ?

Comment: @DinoMyte I tried to build one, but I can't reproduce the problem, I even don't succeed to rebuild my table...